# Moment inequality: $E\mid X_1 X_2 X_3\mid \leq (E(\mid X_1\mid^3)+E(\mid X_2\mid^3)+E(\mid X_3\mid^3))/3 $ for zero-mean r.v.'s?

Tags: self-study, expected-value, inequality

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be zero mean random variables and assume $E(\mid X_i \mid ^{4+\delta})\leq C, i=1,2,3$ where $C$ is a constant and $\delta>0$ some positive small constant.

How can I show that 
$$E(\mid X_1 X_2 X_3 \mid ^r)\leq C_1$$
for $r$ slightly larger than $4/3$?

I appreciate if you can give me some advices!

Comment: The inequality in the title differs from the one in the question.  The title inequality is false.  A variant that is true is $$E|X_1X_2X_3|\le \left(E(|X_1|^3)+E(|X_2|^3)+E(|X_3|^3)\right)/3.$$It holds for all random variables with finite third moments, whether or not they have zero expectations.

Comment: @whuber Excellent! Can you show me or give me reference to prove it?

Comment: This is just the [AM-GM Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Comment: @whubber Great. To answer my question, using this inequality, I should take $\mid X_1^{3r} X_2^{3r} X_3^{3r}\mid^{1/3} (w)\leq (\mid X_1\mid^r+\mid X_2\mid^r+\mid X_3\mid^r)/3 (w), \forall w \in \Omega$ (sample space) and apply the properties of Lebesgue integral, right?

Comment: Yes, that will do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Cauchy-Schwarz inegality.

$E\left(|YZ|^r\right) \leq \sqrt{E\left(|Y|^{2r}\right)E\left(|Z|^{2r}\right)}$. Then

$$E\left(|XYZ|^r\right) \leq \sqrt{E\left(|X|^{2r}\right)\sqrt{E\left(|Y|^{2r}\right)E\left(|Z|^{2r}\right)}}$$

By the way $E\left(|X|^{2r}\right)\leq C$ if $r\leq \tfrac{4+\delta}{2} \geq \tfrac{4}{3}$

After all, $$E\left(|XYZ|^r\right) \leq \sqrt{C\sqrt{CC}} = C$$

Comment: It is not only finite, it is also bounded